# Looking for Ubuntu wallpaper with blue night sky, squid, and astronaut?

Tags: desktop-background

I think it won one of the competitions since 16.04. Big squid on the right side! Help is appreciated!

Comment: You can just add all prior wallpapers to your system; eg. I've added all prior Ubuntu and official flavor wallpapers to my Lubuntu 19.10 system, eg `ubuntu-wallpapers-xenial` contains the wallpapers that came with 16.04 (xenial being the code name for 16.04) so it can be just installed as a normal package.  `gutsy-wallpapers` to get the 7.10 wallpapers, or `ubuntu-gnome-wallpapers-xenial` for the Ubuntu-GNOME 16.04 flavor wallpapers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Posting for others.
https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpapers/comments/9qmpam/encounter_3840x2400_by_lazardjin_ubuntu_1810/